# Solutions for $-\Delta v=\lambda v$ on $\Omega=[0,\pi]^3$

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In Strauss's *Partial Differential Equations*, the eigenvalue problem 
$$-\Delta v=\lambda v,\qquad     v\big|_{\partial \Omega}=0$$
is solved by separating the $x,y,z$ variables: $v=X(x)Y(y)Z(z)$,
$$ \frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}+\frac{Z''}{Z}=-\lambda$$

The separated BCs are $$X(0)=X(\pi)=Y(0)=Y(\pi)=Z(0)=Z(\pi)=0$$

Here are my questions:

- How do we deduce that the solutions are
  $$v(x,y,z)=\sin lx\sin my \sin nz$$ 
  where $$l^2+m^2+n^2=\lambda\quad (1\leq m,l,n<\infty)$$
- Why the shape of $\Omega=[a,b]\times[c,d]\times[e,f]$ is needed for this kind of method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}+\frac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)}=-\lambda,$$ we get that exists $(c_1,c_2,c_3)$ such that 
$$\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} =c_1, \quad\frac{Y''(y)}{Y(y)}=c_2, \quad\frac{Z''(z)}{Z(z)}=c_3$$ and $c_1+c_2+c_3=-\lambda$. You will get the result by solving those differential equations.

We have to define $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ and these functions have to be defined on intervals, which explains the  shape of $\Omega$.

Comment: The point is that $X''(x)/X(x)$ depends only on $x$, but since this is also $-\lambda - Y''(y)/Y(y) - Z''(z)/Z(z)$ which depends only on $y$ and $z$, it must be constant.

As for the shape, $X(x) Y(z) Z(z) = 0$ when one of the three factors is 0.  So you get a boundary consisting of (pieces of) planes where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are constant.